# How to send the session id to the Login API in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, session

i want to create a Login API in symfony . On success login i have to send the Session Id also. This session id is used to authenticate other API's . Please guide to do this.

```
        $this->get('session')->migrate();
        $sid = $this->get('session')->getID();
        // User Login
        $this->loginUser($user);
        $res = array('success'=>1, 'user'=>$user ,'sid'=>$sid , 'message'=>'Login Successfull');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**A simplified version could look like this:**

First of all create the session table (session_id, user_id, created_on)

Then you need a route where the user can send it's credentials to.
For example: /login with Post{username, password}

In the login method you just check in the database if the the user with the given credentials exists.

Then you check if the user already has a active session entry in the database. If not create a unique session id and save it in the database.

Now you can return the data that is needed to the user.